# simple div onclick show javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

when I click on any  link the correspoding div shows up
but when I click the next link, the newly clicked dive shows up as well as the previously clicked. I would like the previos div to hide. NEW to development please some one help me........

this is the html code for links:

```
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('firstimpression'); " href="#">First Impression</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('speaking'); " href="#">Speaking</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('eating'); " href="#">Eating</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('taste'); " href="#">Taste</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('saliva'); " href="#">Saliva</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('cleaning');" href="#">Cleaning</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('nighttime');" href="#">Night Time</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('singledenture');" href="#">Single Denture</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('soreness');"  href="#">Soreness</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('burning');" href="#">Burning</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('adapting');" href="#">Adapting</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('futureconsideration');" href="#">Future Consideration</a>
<a class="hide" onclick="showdiv('conclusion');" href="#">Conclusion</a>
```

these are the divs:

```
<div id="firstimpression" class="patientinfodivs">
<div id="speaking" class="patientinfodivs">
```

.....and so on

Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As much as I hate creating global variables, they just come in so handy sometimes...

```
var _hidediv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(_hidediv)
        _hidediv();
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display = 'block';
    _hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
}
```

This will prevent you from needlessly searching through divs to find the one you should hide.

Edit: Expanding upon @StevenRoose's suggestion:

```
var _targetdiv = null;
function showdiv(id) {
    if(_targetdiv)
        _targetdiv.style.display = 'none';
    _targetdiv = document.getElementById(id);
    _targetdiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: @Nick, why did you chose to keep that function as a global variable instead of a reference to the div? The function would begin with `if(_shownDiv) { _shownDiv.style.display = 'none'; }` in that case

Comment: @StevenRoose, there was no particular reason. I'll append to my answer an expanded version of what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without using a global (other than the function itself). The variable is held on the function object:

```
function showdiv( id ) { 
    if( showdiv.div ) { 
        showdiv.div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    showdiv.div = document.getElementById(id);
    showdiv.div.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need in your showdiv() first make all your elements display = "none";
And then make selected element display = "block";

You can also organize it in two functions hidealldivs(), which will hide all divs and your current showdiv(), which will show selected.

Then onClick call both of them one after another

```
onclick="hidealldivs(); showdiv('eating')"
```

Comment: Would you please provide a code in between script tags for your onclick? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to initially hide your divs. Either in the StyleSheet or inline.

```
.patientinfodivs {
    display: none;
}

<div id="firstimpression" class="patientinfodivs" style="display: none;">
```