# JavaScript change text of div on click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I designed the following structure for my web site, but I don't know how to code it.

I have a div, there is no content in it; lets call it `div="text"`.
Next to this div I got a lot of buttons. When somebody hit a button, the div text need to show the text linked to that button. when another button is clicked the text needs to disappear and the text linked to the button that is clicked needs to show up.

I think I can achieve this by making a lot of divs inside text which are set to `display:none`, as soon as the button is hit I change the display to block, but I don't exactly know how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I recommend to start here: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript.

Comment: You are maybe searching for ".innerHTML" http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: I havent tried anything, My javascript knowledge is to low. I tried to google for it. and found this: $(document).ready(function(){


    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
 $(".show_hide").show();
 
 $('.show_hide').click(function(){
 $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
 });

});

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467943/simple-div-onclick-show-javascript

Comment: Then maybe you should learn a bit more about JavaScript first. I recommend http://eloquentjavascript.net/, especially http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter12.html.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a basic working example](http://jsfiddle.net/GYM5L/) making use of jQuery.

Markup:

```
<div id="display"></div>
<input type="button" value="button 1" />
<input type="button" value="button 2" />
<input type="button" value="button 3" />
​
```

JS:

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
    $('#display').text($(this).val());
});​
```

I recommend you start learning JS. StackOverflow is not for "write it for me".

Comment: No I understand this. I'm sorry. I got the right answare now.. I didnt really mention that I tried things before. cuz I tought it wouldnt matter. What I tried myself was with a link button. it worked oke. but my website moved to the start of the oage since a makes the page load agian. but thanx anyway!