# jquery animate() - how to move / animate just one part of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find a way to have images on a web page float down from the top as well as from the bottom.  I've started with the one that will float down from the top.

(code also available at http://jsfiddle.net/trjthtpf/)

**Code**

Here's the prototype / test code I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
                <title>Title of the document</title>
                <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
       var image = document.getElementById("myimage");
       image.style.display = "block";

        $("#myimage").animate({ 
            marginTop: "400px", 
        }, 10000, "linear"); 
    }); 
/*
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myimage_wrapper").animate({ 
            top: "+=400", 
        }, 10000, "linear"); 
    }); 
*/
</script>

        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>This is a float test</h1>
                <div id="myimage_wrapper">
                        <img id="myimage" src="myimage.jpg" marginTop="0" height="199px" width="253" style="display: none"/>
                </div>
                <h1>this should not move but it does</h1>
        </body>
</html>
```

**What Works / What Doesn't Work**

So the above code will move the "myimage" image from its starting position down the page a few inches on the page, which is great. 
But I have two problem:

1. I would like the image to appear as though it's coming in from off the page.  Sort of like what apple has here: http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/
2. The other problem is that I would like the image to move without moving the other elements on the page.

**What I've so Far**

I've been playing around with DIV tags to see if there's a way to prevent the elements under the image tag from moving.  But so far, no success.

I've also been reviewing this example: [jQuery animate one Div to move down when another one animates up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297861/jquery-animate-one-div-to-move-down-when-another-one-animates-up)
But haven't been able apply the lessons from there here...

Thanks.

Comment: i'm currently trying to add classes to divs like the other stackoverflow post ... and then try to move only the divs of type class X.

Comment: @dot can you make an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: hey @Quoid here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/trjthtpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep a moving object from affecting the rest of the page it must be taken out of the flow of the document. This is done with the css style "position:absolute;".

Your code works fine if you add this style to your css;

```
#diamond_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: -300px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wjkrk2d/

Comment: I agree strongly here with one thing, if possible, have the jquery animated elements set to absolute, with css() or in the stylesheet, whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *loaded* question to a degree.

Firstly, I would approach the animation you are going after, completely different. Unfortunately I am not exactly sure the effect you are attempting, but I believe it is something [like this very basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7evnych/)

The element you are animating is in the document flow and will adjust adjacent elements as it consumes more space (`margin-top` is in a way making that element `x` much bigger). You can remove an element from the document flow with the `position` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Sometimes it is better to make an element `position: absolute`, other times you don't need to depending on other variables (are explicit `heights` or element sizes present?).

Further, I would not personally animate `margin-top`, but use a property like `transform: translate3d(0, -150px, 0);` which I show in my example and I would personally do it mostly through css and just trigger a helper `class` with jQuery.

Here is [your fiddle without](http://jsfiddle.net/trjthtpf/1/) the image affecting positioning of **any** elements, but again this is a raw example and it is better to know the real goal here in order to provide a good approach.

Comment: Quoid, your example is exactly what I'm after!  I'm going to try to adapt it to my code to see if I can get it work

Comment: Quoid, as far as your other comments, I'm not good enough with css to know... an example would be helpful if you have some cycles.

Comment: @dot I can explain a bit better if you can elaborate - what exactly are you after? Two text elements and an element dropping in from the top?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you get started? the image, which i'e replaced in a div, comes in from the side without disrupting the rest of the text. The timeout seems to be needed for stack overflow but should not be necessary otherwise

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
             $("#diamond").removeClass("offscreen");
    }, 100);
});
```

```css
#diamond.offscreen {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all 2s;
}

#diamond {
  background-color:steelblue;
  height: 199px;
  width: 253px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>This is a float test</h1>
<div id="diamond_wrapper">
  <div id="diamond" height="199px" width="253" class="offscreen" />
</div>
<h1>this should not move but it does</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the `diamond_wrapper` to `position:absolute` . That way the element will be out of the normal page flow.

```
.diamond_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: my bad Sushanth, i don't know why the first time i tried it didn't work. i think it's because i needed to replace "." with "#"

Answer (score 0):

No need for any JS for this.
This is all you need:

```
@keyframes odd {
0% {transform: translate(0px,-400px); }
50% {transform: translate(0px,400px); }
100% {transform: translate(0px,-0px); }

}
```

Check it out, let me know if you want some modification on this.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/JYBEdB